# How to unit test date and time selection on a widget using Flutter Date and Time Picker?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

The code below contains the EditableDateTime widget unit test as well as the EditableDateTime stateless widget class definition. The EditableDateTime widget uses the Flutter Date and Time Picker.

Using the EditableDateTime widget on a virtual Android smartphone is shown here:

[image]

My question is how can I test selecting both a date and a time value ? Currently, the testing code tests selecting a day only as well as selecting a month and a day. But trying to test selecting a time as well like shown on the picture was not possible for me, reason why I ask the question.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

/// EditableDateTime widget test code
Future<void> main() async {
  final Finder previousMonthIcon = find.byWidgetPredicate((Widget w) =>
      w is IconButton && (w.tooltip?.startsWith('Previous month') ?? false));

  TextEditingController dateTimePickerController = TextEditingController();

  group(
    'EditableDateTime widget testing',
    () {
      testWidgets(
        'Setting date day only',
        (tester) async {
          await tester.pumpWidget(
            MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                body: EditableDateTime(
                  dateTimeTitle: 'Date time',
                  dateTimePickerController: dateTimePickerController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );

          dateTimePickerController.text = '2022-09-20 12:45';

          TextField textField =
              tester.widget(find.byKey(const Key('editableDateTimeTextField')));

          expect(textField.controller!.text, '2022-09-20 12:45');

          await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('editableDateTimeTextField')));
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          await tester.tap(find.text('14')); // set day
          await tester.tap(find.text('OK'));
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          await tester.tap(find.text('OK'));

          expect(textField.controller!.text, '2022-09-14 12:45');
        },
      );
      testWidgets(
        'Selecting previous date month and setting day only',
        (tester) async {
          await tester.pumpWidget(
            MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                body: EditableDateTime(
                  dateTimeTitle: 'Date time',
                  dateTimePickerController: dateTimePickerController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );

          dateTimePickerController.text = '2022-09-20 12:45';

          TextField textField =
              tester.widget(find.byKey(const Key('editableDateTimeTextField')));

          expect(textField.controller!.text, '2022-09-20 12:45');

          await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('editableDateTimeTextField')));
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          await tester.tap(previousMonthIcon);
          await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1));
          await tester.tap(find.text('6')); // set day
          await tester.tap(find.text('OK'));
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          await tester.tap(find.text('OK'));

          expect(textField.controller!.text, '2022-08-06 12:45');
        },
      );
    },
  );
}

/// EditableDateTime stateless widget definition
class EditableDateTime extends StatelessWidget {
  EditableDateTime({
    Key? key,
    required this.dateTimeTitle,
    required this.dateTimePickerController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static final DateFormat englishDateTimeFormat =
      DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  TimeOfDay _selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
  DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.now();

  final String dateTimeTitle;
  final TextEditingController dateTimePickerController;

  void _updateDateTimePickerValues() {
    _selectedDate = _dateTime;
    _selectedTime = TimeOfDay(hour: _dateTime.hour, minute: _dateTime.minute);
    dateTimePickerController.text = englishDateTimeFormat.format(_dateTime);
  }

  // Select for Date
  Future<DateTime?> _selectDatePickerDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
    );

    if (selectedDate == null) {
      // User clicked on Cancel button
      return null;
    } else {
      if (selectedDate != _selectedDate) {
        _selectedDate = selectedDate;
      }
    }

    return _selectedDate;
  }

  Future<TimeOfDay?> _selectDatePickerTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay? selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _selectedTime,
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Widget? childWidget,
      ) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
            alwaysUse24HourFormat: true,
          ),
          child: childWidget!,
        );
      },
    );

    if (selectedTime == null) {
      // User clicked on Cancel button
      return null;
    } else {
      if (selectedTime != _selectedTime) {
        _selectedTime = selectedTime;
      }
    }

    return _selectedTime;
  }

  Future _selectDatePickerDateTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? date = await _selectDatePickerDate(context);

    if (date == null) {
      // User clicked on date picker dialog Cancel button. In
      // this case, the time picker dialog is not displayed and
      // the _dateTime value is not modified.
      return;
    }

    final TimeOfDay? time = await _selectDatePickerTime(context);

    if (time == null) {
      // User clicked on time picker dialog Cancel button. In
      // this case, the _dateTime value is not modified.
      return;
    }

//    setState(() {
    _dateTime = DateTime(
      date.year,
      date.month,
      date.day,
      time.hour,
      time.minute,
    );
    //  });

    dateTimePickerController.text = englishDateTimeFormat.format(_dateTime);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print('_EditableDateTimeState.build()');
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              dateTimeTitle,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.yellow.shade300,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              // Required to fix Row exception
              // layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity.
              width: 170,
              child: Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
                    selectionColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
                  ),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  key: const Key('editableDateTimeTextField'),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ''),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  controller: dateTimePickerController,
                  readOnly: true,
                  onTap: () {
                    // initializing the date and time dialogs with the
                    // currently displayed date time value ...
                    DateTime currentDateTime = englishDateTimeFormat
                        .parse(dateTimePickerController.text);
                    _selectedTime =
                        TimeOfDay(hour: currentDateTime.hour, minute: currentDateTime.minute);
                    _selectedDate = currentDateTime;
                    _selectDatePickerDateTime(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Curious to hear if you found a solution to this. Dealing with the samen issue right now :) I want to avoid having to add inject a mock function that returns the date, but seems like the way to go I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I suggest injecting a mock function. This will make your tests much easier.

As an example, if you create a date-time getter like this:

```
class CurrentDateTimeGetter {
  DateTime getCurrentDateTime() => DateTime.now();
  TimeOfDay getTimeOfDay() => TimeOfDay.now();
}
```

And define `MyHomePage` as:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CurrentDateTimeGetter dateTimeGetter;

  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.dateTimeGetter});
...
```

Then in your main app, you can inject the getter like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DateTime Picker Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(dateTimeGetter: CurrentDateTimeGetter()),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, regarding the test, mock your getter as follows:

```
class MockCurrentDateTimeGetter implements CurrentDateTimeGetter{
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final TimeOfDay timeOfDay;

  MockCurrentDateTimeGetter({required this.dateTime, required this.timeOfDay});
  
  @override
  DateTime getCurrentDateTime() => dateTime;
  @override
  TimeOfDay getTimeOfDay() => timeOfDay;
}
```

Then you can write a test that validates how to set the date and time, like the one below:

```
void main() {
  final Finder previousMonthIcon = find.byWidgetPredicate((Widget w) => w is IconButton && (w.tooltip?.startsWith('Previous month') ?? false));

  testWidgets("Set date and time in pickers", (tester) async {
    // Arrange
    final initialDate = DateTime(2024, DateTime.january, 19);
    const initialTimeOfDay = TimeOfDay(hour: 6, minute: 30);

    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyHomePage(
          dateTimeGetter: MockCurrentDateTimeGetter(
            dateTime: initialDate, timeOfDay: initialTimeOfDay
          )
        ),
      ),
    ));

    // Act
    // Date selection
    await tester.tap(find.text("Open Date Time Picker"));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    await tester.tap(previousMonthIcon);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    await tester.tap(find.text("25"));
    await tester.tap(find.text("OK")); // Selects 25/12 - 2023
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    // Time selection
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.keyboard_outlined)); // Switch to input entry mode
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.enterText(find.text("6"), "8");
    await tester.enterText(find.text("30"), "15");
    await tester.tap(find.text("OK")); // Select 8:15
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    // Assert
    final textField = tester.widget<TextField>(find.byType(TextField).first);
    final dateTimeText = textField.controller!.text;
    expect(dateTimeText, contains("2023-12-25 08:15"));    
  });
}
```

I drew inspiration from how the authors of showDatePicker and showTimePicker conducted their own testing:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bbfe177dc994308d70aa8e3205ef0b3c0b2651ce/packages/flutter/test/material/time_picker_test.dart#L1778
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/51633fe95c6e5232ed2f6d47426e67d04623dec1/packages/flutter/test/material/date_picker_test.dart#L1056

Answer (score -1):

Using ChatGPT 4 and improving its initially not working code, I finally found how to set a date or time value in the Flutter date time picker. First, it is important to know that you can do this only in a Flutter integration test, not in a Flutter unit test.

The code below is in two parts:

1. a simple Flutter app containing a button which opens a Flutter date time picker and
2. a Flutter integration test which tests this simple app and modifies the hour of the displayed current date time. The comments in the code explain its signification. If you need to modify the date or the minute value, you can adapt your integration test code ...

The simple Flutter app main_date_time_picker.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DateTime Picker Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _dateTimeController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _dateTimeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter DateTime Picker Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _dateTimeController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Selected Date Time',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Open Date Time Picker'),
              onPressed: () async {
                final DateTime? date = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                );
                if (date != null) {
                  final TimeOfDay? time = await showTimePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                  );
                  if (time != null) {
                    final DateTime selectedDateTime = DateTime(
                      date.year,
                      date.month,
                      date.day,
                      time.hour,
                      time.minute,
                    );
                    _dateTimeController.text = selectedDateTime.toString();
                  }
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Flutter integration test main_date_time_picker_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:chatgpt_audio_learn/main_date_time_picker.dart';

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets("Set an hour in the time picker",
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build the app
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    // Find the "Open Date Time Picker" button and tap it
    final openPickerButton = find.text('Open Date Time Picker');
    await tester.tap(openPickerButton);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Confirm the displayed current date
    await tester.tap(find.text('OK'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // in order to set a time in the time picker dialog, we
    // need to tap the keyboard icon displayed at the bottom
    // of the time picker dialog. Then, we will be able to
    // set the hour of the TextField that displays the current
    // hour.

    // Find the IconButton with Icons.keyboard_outlined within
    // the time picker dialog
    final iconButtonFinder = find.descendant(
      of: find.byType(Dialog),
      matching: find.byIcon(Icons.keyboard_outlined),
    );

    // Tap the keyboard IconButton
    await tester.tap(iconButtonFinder);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Now, find the TextField that displays the current hour

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final String currentHour = now.hour.toString();

    final EditableText hourEditableTextWidget =
        tester.widget<EditableText>(find.text(currentHour).first);

    // Verify that the hour displayed in the TextField is the
    // current hour
    expect(currentHour, hourEditableTextWidget.controller.text);

    // Now, modify the time picker hour to 14

    hourEditableTextWidget.controller.text = "14";
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Confirm the selected time
    await tester.tap(find.text('OK'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Verify that the modified hour is displayed
    // in the screen TextField
    final textField = find.byType(TextField);
    expect(
      tester.widget<TextField>(textField).controller!.text.contains('14'),
      true,
    );
  });
}
```